# How can I display the chess board content as strings in C language and store the strings in a table?

Tags: c, c-strings, chess, string-table

How can I display the chess board content as strings in C language (the chess pieces and dots or spaces for the empty spots) and store the strings in a table ?
I can show what I have already done.

Comment: the question is too general. Are you asking about printing to the screen or internal representation? Please share what you have.

Comment: Please show what you have done already and try to be as specific as you can in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! __"I can show..."__ , yes, please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Don't even *think* of trying to make your game compute internally with anything like a represention of  human visible pieces. For a text-based game that's a trivial conversion you do on top of what you have. If you construct your game properly, the internals will be no different when you have nice 3D images of the pieces in a GUI. Always separate **form** from **function**. I suggest you use `enum` definitions for the pieces, so the programmer can easily follow the work, and to facilitate the use of lookup tables.

Comment: There is no use, 4386427 answered the question. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general what you need is an 8x8 array of strings. Since C strings are them selves zero-terminated char arrays, it ends up as a 3D char array.

Something like:

```
#define MAX_TEXT 30
char board[8][8][MAX_TEXT];

int i, j;
for (i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
    for (j=0; j<8; ++j)
    {
        strcpy(board[i][j], ".");  // Make all spots empty
    }
}

strcpy(board[0][1], "knight"); // Put a knight at location (0, 1)

// and so on ...
```

**Update due to comment**

To place the 4 knights using loops, you can do something like:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i = i + 7)  // i will be 0 and 7
{
    for (j=1; j<8; j = j + 5)  // j will be 1 and 6
    {
        strcpy(board[i][j], "knight"); // Put a knight at location (0, 1)
                                       //                          (0, 6)
                                       //                          (7, 1)
                                       //                          (7, 6)
    }
}
```

p.s. I hope the locations are the correct once - I'm not a chess player...

Comment: And is there a way I can add the 4 knights without writing 4 times the word knight ?

Comment: @J.Doe - see updated answer

Comment: The locations are the correct ones ! I compiled and executed the programme and it worked !

Answer (score 4):

```
char board[][sizeof("♜ ♞ ♝ ♛ ♚ ♝ ♞ ♜")] = {
    {"♜ ♞ ♝ ♛ ♚ ♝ ♞ ♜"},
    {"♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟"},
    {"… … … … … … … …"},
    {"… … … … … … … …"},
    {"… … … … … … … …"},
    {"… … … … … … … …"},
    {"♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙"},
    {"♖ ♘ ♗ ♕ ♔ ♗ ♘ ♖"}
};
```

Each piece of the board and the dots are multibyte characters

`strlen("♜")` == 3

`strlen("…")` == 3

An example moving the horse:

```
♜ … ♝ ♛ ♚ ♝ ♞ ♜
♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟
… … ♞ … … … … …
```

---

```
#define ROWS 8
#define DOT "…"
#define MBSZ sizeof(DOT)
#define CELLS (MBSZ + 1)

char *pt1 = board[0] + (CELLS * 1); /* 1 cell */
char *pt2 = board[2] + (CELLS * 2); /* 2 cells */

memmove(pt2, pt1, MBSZ);
memmove(pt1, DOT, MBSZ);

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", board[i]);
}
```

Comment: So cool - maybe not exactly what OP asked for but it's just so much more cool. I would remove the spaces, though.

Comment: Thank you @4386427, looks like a narrow without the spaces, maybe adjusting the font ...

Comment: I can't use Alter Mann's answer, I have question marks instead of pieces

Comment: Indead, it's better ! What can I do to have the pieces like that ?

Comment: @J.Doe, not all terminal fonts supports this, copy/paste in your editor and see what happens.

Comment: The symbole "?" appears instead of pieces.

Comment: In the editor or in the terminal?

Comment: If you are on Windows, you need to save as UTF8 in your editor and some Unicode Font (e.g. "DejaVu") in your terminal instead of "Raster Fonts"

Comment: And how can I do that with Dev C++ ?

Comment: Where are the ?, in the editor or in the terminal?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: In the editor there are ? and in the terminal there is nothing

Comment: I can not help with Dec C++, you need to save your .c as UTF8 but I don't know how, sorry

Comment: Ok ! It's all right ! Thank you for your answers, Alter Mann and 4386427